# Adaptivethemes and panels - how to create custom layout?

Tags: panels, theming

I am building my site using panels , mini panels on every page.
In addition, I am using the panels everywhere modules.
The theme I am using is: "Adaptivetheme".

I every page I built (using page manager and panels), I chose a panels layout of "AT responsive panels" 3 or 2 columns, depends on the page.

can I change the ratio of the columns of the layouts, so it will be, for examples 20/55/25, instead of the default 25/50/25?

Answer (score 2):

> Panels - how to create custom layout?

In Panels, (or Adaptive), find the directory `layouts` directory.

In it, each layout has it's own directory with a couple of files in it.

Copy any of these directories, rename all the files to the new name of the directory, and you have a new plugin.

Also see the comment for the function `at_get_plugins` which provides `Ctools` specific integration so you can subtheme AT and have new layouts in your subtheme.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to panel layouts specifically for Adaptivetheme, you should refer to [this drupal.org discussion](https://www.drupal.org/node/1674192).